# Error when making value in column as a new column name?

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

What I am trying to do produce the average "1_Bed_Effective_Rent_Per_Unit_Modified" for each "SubMarket" within a "Year". I took the average of four quarters in a year for each "SubMarket" with this line
`df = county_rental_df.groupby(["Year", "SubMarkets"])["1_Bed_Effective_Rent_Per_Unit_Modified"].mean()` and got this output as a series

| Year | SubMarkets | 1_Bed_Effective_Rent_Per_Unit_Modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 Ward | 1148.50 |
|  | 2 Ward | 2683.00 |
| 2001 | 1 Ward | 896.00 |
|  | 2 Ward | 2107.50 |

I then made the series into a data frame using this `df_1 = df.to_frame()`

The year column only has the year printed once for each year like shown in the above table.

What I want I want the final product to look like is

| SubMarkets | 2000 | 2001 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Ward | 1148.50 | 896.00 |
| 2 Ward | 2683 | 2107.50 |

so I used this line `df_1_2 = df_1.pivot(index='SubMarkets', columns='Year', values='1_Bed_Effective_Rent_Per_Unit_Modified')\.reset_index()` and I get an error "KeyError: 'SubMarkets'". How can I fix this to get my desired output?

Comment: You could use: `df.unstack(level=0).droplevel(0, axis=1)` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need reset the index of `df_1` before pivot

```py
df_1 = df_1.reset_index()

df_1_2 = df_1.pivot(index='SubMarkets', columns='Year', values='1_Bed_Effective_Rent_Per_Unit_Modified')
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I guess my question is now. When I tried to convert the output of df_1_2 into a csv file using df_1_2.to_csv("1_Bed") nothing was in its own row and everything was in 1 column. Is there another file that I need to turn df_1_2 in to get a csv or xlsx?

Comment: @ChrisMcManus I couldn't reproduce.